# Too many arguments to function excel, Budget Calculator

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I am creating a budgeting tool which will use billing as weekly, monthly and quarterly drop-down boxes, and by selecting the drop-down box it calculates the monthly value in the next column over.
where-in the only information you need to input is the dollar amount and if it is weekly, monthly or quarterly.

The code I have currently is;

```
=IF(C6="Monthly",B6, IF(C6="Weekly", (B6*52)/12), IF(C6="Quarterly", (B6\12)*3, ))
```

and I am getting the error

> "too many arguments to function excel"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answered =IF(C6="Monthly",B6,IF(C6="Quarterly",B6/12*3,IF(C6="Weekly",B6*52/12)))